# How can I take a words from a text document with a common letter and copy them to another?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, document

I'm trying to print words from a document into the python terminal and then use a for loop to print out all the words with the character 'e'.

```
file = open("myfile.txt", 'r')
file = file.read()
print(file)
input('Press enter to all words with \'e\'')
for line in file:
    for words in line.split(' '):
        for letters in words:
            if words == 'e':
                print(words)
```

The problem I'm having is that this is only going to print `e` for the number of times it showed up in the document. I'm trying to figure out how to pull the full word if it has the character `e` I'm not sure what I need to do.

I'm trying to get the output to look like this

```
text
document
testing
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looking for each and every character in word using `for` loop, you can use `in` operator for searching through the words. For details about [`in` keyword check this out](http://kracekumar.com/post/22512660850/python-in-operator-use-cases).

You can try this (in python 3):

```
line = 'Press enter to Exit.'
for words in line.split(' '):
    if 'e' in words:
        print(words)
```

Output:

```
Press
enter
```

See Here ,`Exit` is not getting printed because we are only searching for `'e'` But if you want `'E'` also you can try `if 'e' in words or 'E' in words:`.

We can also do this by *List comprehension* as:

```
line = 'Press enter to all words with e'
print([words for words in line.split() if 'e' in words])
```

Output:

```
['Press', 'enter', 'e']
```

But it will form a list of words which contains letter `'e'`.

hope this will help you.